# Do financial institutions specially approve loans to pay the Church of Scientology?

Tags: united-states, banking, scientology

This is about claims made by Steven Mango (who appeared also in the "My Scientology Movie", directed by John Dower) between the 1:00 - 2:30 points in this video titled "[Top 5 Craziest Experiences I Had In Scientology](https://youtu.be/jxcVkl7FIRg?t=1m)".

According to Mr Mango, a registrar at the "Celebrity Center" (operated by the Church of Scientology) had told him that the church "had people higher up in American Express and other financial institutions" that can underwrite and approve loans for the people.

Here is a transcript of what Steven Mango says between 1:00 - 2:30 points (emphasis added):

> Annie told me, at Celebrity Center, that they had people higher up in
>   American Express and other financial institutions that can underwrite
>   and approve your loan, or your credit card rather, in order for you to
>   be able to go up the "bridge" and to pay for more services.
>
> And I did not believe it at first because I did get declined. And then
>   she said "Hey, it doesn't matter if you get declined. That's the first
>   step. Now we have to go and handle the bank."
>
> **And they had someone in American Express that would be able to approve your credit card, or for your loan, or for any sort of
>   financial product that they were trying to get for you, so that you
>   would be able to go up the "bridge", take another course, do another
>   service.** But for me it was for me to get tens of thousands of
>   dollars for me to go "clear".
>
> That was one of the crazy money situations that I never forgot when
>   she said that to me. She looked me dead in the eye and told me and
>   pulled out her appoint...not like her appointment book, she pulled out
>   like her, like, contacts book and they had all different bank files.
>
> Like there is one for like U.S. Bank, one for Bank of America, and
>   there's different names. There's like direct lines to like those
>   specific people. And there was like all this different information in
>   regards to the banks and what they had to do, in order to...and there
>   is even a script. They had a script as well in order to contact the
>   banks, or whatever.

During the approximately 5 years that Steven Mango was a member at Church of Scientology, the church had racked up a debt of approximately $50,000 USD under his name. He was not able to make the minimum payments (about $1200 USD/month according to what he says in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFj2BFmGb1Q)) and says that it was difficult to even pay $200/month at that time.

So it looks like he should never have been awarded the level of debt that the church obtained in his name.

Does the Church of Scientology have their own people at high levels at the financial institutions, to allow their followers to borrow money to pay the church?

Comment: I don't think it's that hard to get banks to loan you money that you are unable to pay-- probably millions of people have unsustainable credit card debt.  It's easy to imagine that Scientology would have a script or procedures to follow to 'help' you get in that situation; that wouldn't require specific collaborators at banks or credit card compaines.

Comment: Is this a matter of institutions financing more non-specified personal debt than they should (many, many people without the means to pay have racked up tens of thousands in personal loan and credit card debt), or actually approving loans specifically for use for Scientology members, as members?